# What does $\mathbb P\{X>x\mid \mathcal A\}$ mean?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-expectation

Let $(\Omega \times \Omega ', \mathcal F\times \mathcal A,\mathbb P)$ a probability space. In fact $\mathcal A=\sigma \{\alpha_i\mid i\in\mathbb N\}$ where $\alpha _i\in [0,1]$ are random variable (iid but it's not important for my question). Let $$X:\Omega\times \Omega '\longrightarrow \mathbb R$$ a random variable. What does $\mathbb P\{X\leq x\mid \mathcal A\}$ mean ? So, I know that it's a r.v. that is $\mathcal A-$ measurable and it's defined by $$\mathbb E[\boldsymbol 1_{\{X\geq x\}}\mid \mathcal A].$$

**Q1)** Now, since $\mathcal A$ has only element in $[0,1]$ does it imply that $\mathbb P\{X\leq x\mid \mathcal A\}\in [0,1]$ a.s. ?

**Q2)** If for example $\mathcal A$ was the $\sigma -$algebra of borel set, could we have $\mathbb P\{X\geq x\mid \mathcal A\}$ ? (I know it look stupide for a probability to be bigger than $1$, but since it's a r.v., after all, why not...)

**Q3)** If I have that $\mathbb P\{X\leq x\mid \mathcal A\}=f(\alpha _1,...,\alpha _n)$ for example, in this situation (since it's $\mathcal A-$ measurable) can the $\alpha _i$ be seen as "fix number" ? I know they are not, but in proof, I often see : fix a sequence "$\alpha _0,\alpha _1,...$", so maybe in this situation they can be seen as fixed number (in the context conditional by $\mathcal A$)

Comment: Sorry but do you have a definition of conditional expectation with respect to a sigma-algebra, at your disposal?

Comment: @Did: Yes, it's the one I wrote : $\mathbb P\{B\mid \mathcal A\}=\mathbb E[\boldsymbol 1_B\mid \mathcal A]$.

Comment: Which assumes you would know a rigorous definition of $E(Y\mid\mathcal A)$ for a random variable $Y$. Do you?

Comment: @Did: yes I do, it's the on $\mathcal G-$measurable function s.t. $\mathbb E[YX]=\mathbb E[Y\mathbb E[X\mid \mathcal G]]$ for bounded and $\mathcal G-$ measurable r.v. $Y$.

Comment: This settles your Q3), it seems. Your Q2) is not a question. Any idea about your Q1)?

Comment: @Did: thanks for your Hint, but I don't really understand why it answer the question 3... Could you please enlighten me ? For Q2), I wanted to say "could we have $\mathbb P\{X\leq x\mid \mathcal A\}>1$ ? For Q1) since all $\alpha _i$ are in $[0,1]$ I would say yes, but since $\mathbb P\{X\leq x\mid \mathcal A\}=f(\alpha _{n_1},...,\alpha _{n_k})$ for a $\mathcal A-$measurable function, to me it could also be bigger that $1$ (since we don't know much about $f$).

Comment: Whether the $\alpha_i$s are in $[0,1]$ with full probability or not is quite irrelevant. But the fact that $0\leqslant\mathbf 1_{X\geqslant x}\leqslant1$ almost surely, indeed implies that $0\leqslant P(X\geqslant x\mid\mathcal A)\leqslant1$ almost surely.

Comment: @Did: ok, thank you. And for Q3) ?

Comment: Already solved. Or explain.

Comment: @Did: I'm sorry but I didn't understand the answer. In what $\mathbb E[XY]=\mathbb E[Y\mathbb E[X\mid \mathcal G]]$ answer my question ? Thank you.

Comment: Last try (from me, anyway): Please explain what Q3) is really asking.

Comment: @Did: If conditional by $\mathcal A$ allow us to consider element that are $\mathcal A-$ measurable as "fix" (i.e. as element and not random function). For example, when I right $\mathbb P\{...\mid \mathcal A\}=\alpha _i$ where $\alpha _i$ is $\mathcal A$ measurable, can I consider in this precise case that $\alpha _i$ is a fix number ?

Comment: When one writes $P(X>x\mid\mathcal A)=\alpha$, one means that $P(X>x\mid\mathcal A)(\omega)=\alpha(\omega)$ for $P$-almost every $\omega$. Remember that $P(X>x\mid\mathcal A)$ is, by definition, a (class of) random variable(s).